# Opening specific area only

Tags: shapefile

I have a shapefile loaded of a County boundary, but I would like to open another shapefile but only show the lines etc. within that area and automatically delete anything outside.

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: Hi @Mike, welcome to GIS.se :) In order to generate useful answers you'll need to give readers enough background to understand your dilemma. For example, what software you're using, what procedures you've tried already, the particular concepts or terminology that you don't understand, and so on.

Answer (score 5):

In ArcMap 10.1:

Clip the dataframe to the extent of the layer.

Dataframe Properties > Data Frame > Clip Options

You could also [clip](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000004000000) a new shapefile based on the county boundary. There are probably more ways, but these are the first that come to mind.